# UITableView in UIView in UIScrollview : On tap in UITableView data gets cleared

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

For work purposes I need to create a UIScrollView which embeds a UIView which in his turn embeds an UITableView via the container feature in Xcode.

My UIScrollView is a full page scrollview with Paging enabled. 
My UIView is filled with a UIImage, some UIButton's and a container linking to a UITableView.

On initial launch, the data is loaded perfectly, meaning the UITableView is filled with the data, the UIImage is filled, and the Buttons are placed correctly.

But for some strange reason the when I try to tap or scroll in the UITableView in the container all the data from my UITableView gets cleared.

I'm posting this question here, as I have not found any other similar issue on StackOverFlow or any other website.

UITableViewCode:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.productTable setBackgroundView:nil];
    self.productTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.productTable.delegate = self;
    self.productTable.dataSource = self;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    /*CGSize tmp = self.productTable.contentSize;
    self.productTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tmp.width, tmp.height * 3);*/


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"section count : %i", [self.Products count]);
    return [self.Products count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    xcsSectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.Products objectAtIndex:section];
    if (sectionInfo.isOpen == NO) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    xcsSectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.Products objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)  {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Header";
        xcsProductHeaderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.articleNumber.text = sectionInfo.product.articleNumber;
        cell.articleColor.text = sectionInfo.product.articleColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        if (sectionInfo.isOpen == YES && sectionInfo == self.currentSectionInfo) {
            cell.expandImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"];
        } else if (sectionInfo.isOpen == NO) {
            cell.expandImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"];
        }
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductHeader";
        xcsProductTitleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.colorTempHeader.text = @"Color Temperature";
        cell.sourceQualityHeader.text = @"Source Quality";
        cell.sourceTypeHeader.text = @"Source Type";
        cell.luminaireFluxHeader.text = @"Luminaire Flux";
        cell.powerConsumptionHeader.text = @"Power Consumption";
        cell.luminaireEfficacyHeader.text = @"Luminaire Efficacy";
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Product";
        xcsProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.colorTemp.text = sectionInfo.product.colorTemperature;
        cell.sourceQuality.text = sectionInfo.product.sourceQuality;
        cell.sourceType.text = sectionInfo.product.sourceType;
        cell.luminaireFlux.text = sectionInfo.product.luminaireFlux;
        cell.powerConsumption.text = sectionInfo.product.powerConsumption;
        cell.luminaireEfficacy.text = sectionInfo.product.luminaireEfficacy;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        xcsSectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.Products objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSIndexPath *path0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row]+1 inSection:[indexPath section]];
    NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row]+2 inSection:[indexPath section]];
            NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: path0, path1, nil];
    if (sectionInfo.isOpen == NO) {
        sectionInfo.isOpen = YES;
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:NO];
    } else {
        sectionInfo.isOpen = NO;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:NO];
    }
    [self.Products replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:sectionInfo];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    self.currentSectionInfo = sectionInfo;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Btw.: I'm using storyboards

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code of your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**:

I think a `UIPageViewController` would be more appropriate ([link‌​](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)). It looks like it accomplishes what you are trying to achieve. And probably much more simple than managing scroll views embedded in other scroll views.

---

**UPDATE**:

It looks like what you are trying to achieve is made possible in the `UIPageViewController` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)). If this works, it would be better than trying to manage scroll views embedded in other views.

---

Embedding a `UITableView` is specifically NOT recommended by Apple. Conflicts arise when the system is trying to figure out where to send events:

> **Important**: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.
>   ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

But here is the stupid part, when you go to the source link, you will notice that appears in the docs for the `UIWebView`. **Apple forgot to include it in the docs for** `UITableView`.

Comment: I understand that it is not recommended by Apple. 
It means it can be done.

Comment: @NDakotaBE It can, but it is often more trouble than it is worth (You can sift through [these](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Embedding+UITableView+inside+a+UIScrollView&oq=embedding&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39j0l3.5018.6278.0.9790.9.9.0.0.0.0.182.1128.1j8.9.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.EkMFnyYhtK8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.dmQ&fp=eb9fa80f02048b55&biw=1352&bih=841) posts if you like. But we do not control what goes on internally with any of those classes, so what ever work around you discover may break in the future.

Comment: That's a fact. 
The problem is that I need to create a viewcontroller in which I can page through dynamically generated views which in their turn have TableViewControllers in them.
I can't use anything else in my opinion due to the fact I have to place extra data above the table. 
Any ideas?

Comment: @NDakotaBE Maybe using a `UIPageViewController` would be more appropriate ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)). I have never used it, but it looks like it accomplishes what you are trying to achieve. And probably much more simple than managing scroll views embedded in other scroll views..

Comment: Could you please add this to your answer? I'll accept it then. Stupid of me I didn't think of that

Comment: @MikeD Can the app get rejected for using TableView in a ScrollView ?

Comment: @thedp That by it self, I doubt it. However, if bugs are [readily apparent](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)(login required), there is a chance it will get rejected. That "unexpected behaviour" mentioned in my answer may cause some bad things.